# R tree plot text for factors broken and written as 'a',' bfgj' or 'bcdefghij'?

Tags: r, plot, text

```
tree <- rpart(hit ~. , data = train, control = rpart.control(minbucket = 5))
plot(tree, main = "Decision Tree")
text(tree)
```

[image: Decision tree plot]

(I deleted independent variable names from the image)

**My problem is that factor names written as 'a', 'b', 'c', bcdefghijl', and 'bfgj' etc., instead of the real factor names.** I tried both of the code below, but not resolving the issue. How to fix it?

```
df$var1<-as.factor(df$var1)
df$var1<-as.factor(as.character(df$var1))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Wrong labels in rpart tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602548/wrong-labels-in-rpart-tree)

I found this link has good answer for this. 
just don't use rpart plot, but lbrary(rpart.plot)